# Backup and restore SQLite database to sdcard in Xamarin Android C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-backup-service

I want to implement backup and restore database in android with xamarin android C#.
My database is Sqlite and I want to backup db to SdCard.
AnyOne Can Help Me?
The code below is some My code

```
string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

    public bool createDataBase()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Plans.db")))
            {
                connection.CreateTable<Plan>();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {

            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: just use the normal System.IO file operations to copy Plans.db

Comment: @Jason please write and post the code for that operation(System.IO file operations).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
  var dbFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
  var dbFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(dbFolder, "my_test.sqlite");
  var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(GetLoggerDir(), "my_test.sqlite");

  FileStream readStream = new FileStream(dbFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
  FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
  ReadWriteStream(readStream, writeStream);
```

GetLoggerDir() method

```
  public static string GetLoggerDir()
    {
        Java.IO.File dataDir = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/" + "YourFolderName" + "/");
        if (!dataDir.Exists())
            dataDir.Mkdirs();
        return dataDir.ToString();
    }
```

Add permissions in Manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also add runtime permission

A folder will create with name "YourFolderName" in the device sdCard. First copy that file to any other folder of the device then we can copy to PC for the specific purpose.
I hope it will work perfectly.